# controlNav of Flexslider with 2 digitals

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am using **Flexslider plugin** with

> controlNav=true

I get the pagination for slide is  `[ 1 2 3 ]`.
Is there any way I can get it  `[ 01  02  03]`
(Add 0 before)
Thanks,

Comment: That is the way numbers get stored in an array.

Comment: I just mean 01 02 03, no square barrack

Comment: could you post the code which causes this.

Comment: `$('#mainslide').flexslider({
    namespace       :   "flex-",
    selector        :   ".slides > li",
    controlNav      :   true
});`